# Can I use a plastic cup instead of a ramekin for my panna cotta?

Tags: equipment, storage

I don't have ramekins or custard cups.  Can I pour the warm (not hot) cream-buttermilk mixture of panna cotta into plastic cups to refrigerate?

Answer (score 4):

Yup, you can use any small food safe receptacle.